# Problems when exporting .mu file

Tags: scene

I was trying to import some models and Blender send me this error message :

attribute error : "scene" object has no attribute "cursor_location"

Someone knows what is it ?

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Are you using Blender 2.8? Then it's an add-on that wasn't properly ported from 2.79 because it's `bpy.context.scene.cursor.location` in the new API.

Comment: rjg The model came from version 2.79, which I exported in blender 2.8 to export it in .mu. The message appeared when I reimported the .mu in blender 2.8.

Comment: And where is the add-on for importing and exporting .mu from? It doesn't seem to be official add-on that ships with Blender.

Comment: rjg this addon come from here : https://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/40056-12-17-blender-280-mu-importexport-addon/

Answer (score 1):

This error has already been fixed by commit [5eea1995659bf17a0c716b1207207333f85fb67b](https://github.com/taniwha/io_object_mu/commit/5eea1995659bf17a0c716b1207207333f85fb67b). Remove the currently used add-on and install the most recent version of the .mu importer/exporter add-on to solve this problem.

Comment: Ok thank you but i already have the latest version of the addon.

Comment: @Lgg159 That can't be right, the current version of the repository has no `cursor_location` in it anymore. The add-on you have installed has to be an older version.

Comment: Ok so Blender dont send me the error message but there is another problem : there is nothing in the mu file...

Comment: @Lgg159 without any error message I can't help. You may see warning if you take a look at the Blender console. For further assistance you better create an issue on the GitHub page of the add-on.